Failed to deploy Shopware 6 Dockware into Render
I want to deploy a Dockerware/play image into Render (https://dashboard.render.com/). I choose Deploy an existing image from a registry option and use this registry link (https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/dockware/play) for deployment
I got this message (in the image below) and its failed, although in my local works very well.
(https://i.sstatic.net/8317SATK.png)
So I would like to know how can I solve this issue, thanks in advance!!!

The reason I want to deploy is because Shopware does not allow installing Plugin on the Store locally, so I need to have a Shopware app with a real domain to download necessary plugins, then install them on my local codebase
